# Proving Union of Ensemble is not Empty_set

Tags: coq

Working with the `Ensembles` library, I'd like to show that the union of an `Ensemble` with a singleton is not `Empty_set`.

```
Lemma aze: Singleton nat 1 <> Empty_set nat.
```

However, I have no idea how to prove that. I'd be happy to say what I tried, but except playing with `auto`, `intro` and `simpl`, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Assume `H1 : Singleton nat 1 = Empty_set nat` (by `intro H1`). You now have to prove `False`.
2. Assert (= prove) `H2 : Empty_set nat -> False`.
3. Rewrite to `H2 : Singleton nat 1 -> False` via `H1`.
4. Assert `H3 : Singleton nat 1`.
5. `H2 H3 : False`.